# ANTLR4: How to disable/enable skip of the whitespaces in the rule?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have such grammar:

```
grammar SearchQuery;

queryDeclaration                        : predicateGroupItem predicateGroupItemWithBooleanOperator* ;
predicateGroupItemWithBooleanOperator   : groupOperator predicateGroupItem ;
predicateGroupItem                      : LEFT_BRACKET variable variableDelimiter
                                                expression expressionWithBoolean* RIGHT_BRACKET ;

variable                                : VARIABLE_STRING ;
variableDelimiter                       : VAR_DELIMITER  ;

expressionWithBoolean                   : boolOperator expression ;

expression                              : value ;

value                                   : polygonType;

boolOperator                            : or
                                        ;

or                                      : OR ;

groupOperator                           : AND ;

polygonType                             : POLYGON LEFT_BRACKET pointList (POLYGON_DELIMITER pointList)* RIGHT_BRACKET ;
longType                                : LONG ;
doubleType                              : DOUBLE ;

pointList                               : point
                                        | LEFT_BRACKET point ( POLYGON_DELIMITER point)* RIGHT_BRACKET
                                        ;

point                                   : latitude longitude ;

latitude                                : longType
                                        | doubleType
                                        ;

longitude                               : longType
                                        | doubleType
                                        ;

POLYGON                                 : [pP] [oO] [lL] [yY] [gG] [oO] [nN] ;


LONG                                    : DIGIT+ ;

DOUBLE                                  : DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT*
                                        | '.' DIGIT+
                                        ;

AND                                     : [aA] [nN] [dD] ;
OR                                      : COMMA
                                        | [oO] [rR]
                                        ;

VARIABLE_STRING                         : [a-zA-Z0-9.]+ ;
COMMA                                   : ',' ;
POLYGON_DELIMITER                       : ';' ;
VAR_DELIMITER                           : ':' ;

RIGHT_BRACKET                           : ')' ;
LEFT_BRACKET                            : '(' ;

WS                                      : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;

fragment DIGIT                          : [0-9] ;
```

Problem is that I need to disable global skip of the whitespaces in the point rule, because of when I will test such grammar with a value like this

```
(Location: POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10)))
```

I will get the value of the polygonType in the visitor like this

```
POLYGON((3010,4040,2040,1020,3010))
```

As you can see all points are without spaces...

Thanks for the future answer.

Comment: I think you will find that your visitor correctly sees two integers for each point. It's printing them out without a space between them, but that should be easy to fix if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already commented by rici: the numbers are not glued together. If you invoke a `toString()` or `getText()` (or similar) on a parser context, it will simply return a string representation of itself. This string representation will not include spaces because those are skipped by the lexer.

The context will have separate tokens for the numbers. It will not have a token containing the input `3010`, but will contain 2 tokens for it: `30` and `10`.

Set a breakpoint in your visitor and see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks a ton, @rici and Bart Kiers. I thought that there is some solution to fix this situation in grammar, without coding in a visitor. Looks like I have no choice and should fix visitor :(